# LeadConvert getAccountId() isn't working as expected, returns nothing

Tags: lead-conversion

I'm trying to change the record type of a newly created account following  lead conversion.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm) states that:

*getAccountId() - Gets the ID of the account into which the lead will be merged.*

However, the method returns nothing while I expect it to return the newly account's id.

```
for (Lead l : (List<Lead>)Trigger.New) {
    if (l.RecordTypeId == investorLeadRecordTypeId) {
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(l.id);
        lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted_to_Opportunity');
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());  

        Id accId = lc.getAccountId();
        accIds.add(accId);                 
    }
}
// code below isn't running because accIds is empty
if (!accIds.isEmpty()) {
    List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId FROM Account WHERE Id in: accIds];
    for (Account acc : accs) {
        acc.RecordTypeId = investorAccountRecordTypeId;
    }
    update accs;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LeadConvert` object won't have the Id for an Account that was to be created. Just use the `LeadConvertResult.getAccountId()` method instead - it will have the id used, whether it was a newly created or existing account. Only one additional letter needed in your code!

```
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());  

Id accId = lcr.getAccountId();
accIds.add(accId);
```

Comment: Sweet! works like a charm, thank you.